# Replicate "Merge Contact" Related List button behavior on Account Detail Page in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, duplicate-management, merge, findduplicates

We are migrating to Lightning from Classic, we found that "**Merge Contact**" button is not available in Lightning on Account Page.

[image]

I see that there is standard component Named "Potential Duplicate", can be used only on Detail Page, so cannot be used in my case.

I want to show button on Contact Related List available on Account Page similar to Classic behavior, see above attached snip.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer, so I'm writing a comment. In my org, we needed to activate a duplicate rule on `Contact` to be able to get some merge functionality. Not sure if that gave us access to that "potential duplicate" component, a button, or both. Just something worth looking into.

Comment: @DerekF Yes, I looked into it, but it doesn't help here.